# ExtJS and this.control query

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have an issue with the next code block:

```
run: function(e, row){
    var me = this;

    var container = Ext.getCmp('centercontainer');

    try {
        container.removeAll();
    } catch(e) {  }

    // This block is called from another file, I just put it here to show you.
    me.panels = [{
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        id: 'containertabpanel',
        items: [{
            itemId: 'package',
            title: me.PackageTitle
        },{
            itemId: 'excursion',
            title: me.ExcursionTitle
        }]
    }];

    // Reset
    container.setTitle(me.EditDestinationTitle + row.data.name);
    container.add(me.panels);
    me.tabs = container.getComponent('containertabpanel');

    // console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#containertabpanel > #package'))

    me.control({
        // Work with 
        // 'tab': {

        // Doesn't work
        'containertabpanel > package': {
            mouseover: me.doPackage
        }
    })

},
```

Anyone knows how do I get to catch the click event of "package" item of tabpanel component?
I saw when I use just "tab" selector on this.control query, that work, but I can't get only "package" tab component.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your definition of your tabpanel you can specify -

```
listeners:{
    click:{
        fn: function(){
           //click handling code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this is controller code and you are trying to catch an item click on the panel which is one of many in a tabpanel

What you can do is identify your panel by any property that is unique to it via the component query syntax like this:   `button[myprop=blah]`
This syntax will match any buttons on the page with the following config:

```
{
    xtype:'button' 
    myprop:'blah'
}
```

In your case you can try `tab[itemId=package]`

What you also need to be careful about is controller can listening only for events that are fired by the components. Make sure the event you are listening for is fired (check the docs). You can always fire custom events if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

```
me.control({
    // Work with 
    // 'tab': {

    // Doesn't work
    'containertabpanel > #package': {
        mouseover: me.doPackage
    }
})
```